# Which kind of proxy service should I install on my dedicated web server?

Tags: linux, security, proxy

I have a dedicated server and would like to install proxy on my server so that I secure it. I'm not sure which type of proxy is suitable for me. Any help clarifying what is web proxy and what is the type suitable for me would be greatly appreciated. My apologies if the question is silly, actually I'm a beginner in the field.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve - or what services do you want to access to? IMO using SSH could be a simple way to manage your server and even access its services - using SSH port forwarding or even SSH tunneling (which creates a proxy in your client system that routes traffic through your server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proxy server is usually neither a necessary nor a a useful security feature for infrastructure that consists of only a single server.

In general when people do need proxy functionality on a single web server it is in the role of a *”reverse proxy”*.

You need a reverse proxy when for instance you need to seamlessly integrate on the default http and https ports different web applications that each run on a different application servers I.e. when you have both java, python and ruby applications as well as static content.

You can often use the reverse proxy capability that is already built into the web server software of your choice